# SQL Server Management Studio stuck at end or takes very long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am installing SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but it gets stuck at end of the installation (as can be seen in the screenshot) or takes a very long time (a complete night) but nothing happens.

I have

- Windows 8.1 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2013

Any guidance?

[image]

Comment: I have seen fake-outs like this before, and it usually means that something is just failing at the end.  Do you have admin rights on your machine?

Comment: Yes! This is my personal machine..

Comment: Have you tried running the installation as administrator?

Comment: Also, have you tried SSMS 2017 instead? If so, does it suffer the same problem?

Comment: your screenshot suggests you try to install a 32 bit on a 64 bit host maybe?

Comment: @Y.S SSMS is a 32bit application. There is no 64bit version. 32bit applications run fine on a 64bit system though.

Comment: @Y.S lots of apps are still 32bit only and will run fine in a 64 bit environment. In certain cases it's actually an advantage. The opposite way round would certainly be a problem though.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu SSMS 2017 Has successfully installed on my machine

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue in the past and I found that by killing off this installation (Task manager) and then issue the following:

Setup.exe /SkipInstallerRunCheck from command line, obviously you will have to navigate to the installation folder.